# Flutter iOS build failed an error of pod files: Podfile is out of date

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter, podfile

I'm trying to build my app on the iOS simulator ([iOS 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_13)), but the build fails and gives an error of pod files *"Podfile is out of date"*

This is the error.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Warning: Podfile is out of date
  This can cause a mismatched version of Flutter to be embedded in your app, which may result in App Store submission rejection or crashes.
  If you have local Podfile edits you would like to keep, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24641 for instructions.
To regenerate the Podfile, run:
  rm ios/Podfile

Warning: Podfile is out of date
  This can cause issues if your application depends on plugins that do not support iOS.
  See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#plugin-platforms for details.
  If you have local Podfile edits you would like to keep, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45197 for instructions.
To regenerate the Podfile, run:
  rm ios/Podfile

Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            7,8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/kareldebedts/developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.11/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:155:24: error: no visible @interface for 'FIRQuery' declares the selector 'queryWhereField:arrayContainsAny:'
            query = [query queryWhereField:fieldName arrayContainsAny:value];
                     ~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/kareldebedts/developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.11/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:157:24: error: no visible @interface for 'FIRQuery' declares the selector 'queryWhereFieldPath:arrayContainsAny:'
            query = [query queryWhereFieldPath:fieldPath arrayContainsAny:value];
                     ~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/kareldebedts/developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.11/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:163:24: error: no visible @interface for 'FIRQuery' declares the selector 'queryWhereField:in:'
            query = [query queryWhereField:fieldName in:value];
                     ~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/kareldebedts/developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.11/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:165:24: error: no visible @interface for 'FIRQuery' declares the selector 'queryWhereFieldPath:in:'
            query = [query queryWhereFieldPath:fieldPath in:value];
                     ~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/kareldebedts/developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.11/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:764:16: warning: 'timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          settings.timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = (bool)call.arguments[@"timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled"];
                   ^
    In module 'FirebaseFirestore' imported from /Users/kareldebedts/DRINKM8/drinkm8_git/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:31:
    /Users/kareldebedts/DRINKM8/drinkm8_git/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/Source/Public/FIRFirestoreSettings.h:69:20: note: 'timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        __attribute__((deprecated));
                       ^
    1 warning and 4 errors generated.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

I tried `rm ios/Podfile`, but the terminal says the command doesn't exist.

This is my `pubspec.yaml`.

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+12
  flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.7+1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
  geolocator: ^5.1.1+1
  url_launcher: ^5.1.2
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  flutter_picker: ^1.0.13
  uuid: 2.0.1
  image_picker: ^0.6.1
  path_provider: ^1.2.0
  image: ^2.1.4
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.4
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.2.5
  intl: ^0.15.8
  native_contact_picker: ^0.0.6
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.0.0
  transparent_image: ^1.0.0
  connectivity: ^0.4.3+7
  flare_splash_screen: ^2.1.3
  algolia: ^0.1.6+1
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  cloud_functions: ^0.4.1+6
  firebase_messaging: ^5.0.2
  avatar_glow: ^1.0.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.21+8
  geoflutterfire: ^2.0.2
  rxdart: ^0.22.2
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
  camera: ^0.5.4+1
  video_player: ^0.10.2+1
  story_view: ^0.11.0
  thumbnails: ^1.0.1
  image_crop: ^0.3.1
  file_picker: ^1.4.2
  pdf_viewer_plugin: ^1.0.0+2
  flutter_background_geolocation: ^1.3.2
  location_permissions: ^2.0.3
  image_downloader: ^0.19.1
  permission_handler: ^3.3.0
  firebase_database: ^3.1.0
```

What can cause the problem? Maybe it's because I upgraded the simulator to iOS 13.

Comment: Re *"pubspec yaml"*: Do you file *[pubspec.yaml](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec)*?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This mostly happens when you upgrade your Flutter application. To solve this issue, follow the below steps

1. Go to *Your_Project_Directory/ios/* and remove *Podfile* or you can do it by running the following command in the root project directory

   ```
   rm ios/Podfile
   ```
2. *Run* your project again. This will create a new and updated *Podfile* for you

   ```
   flutter run
   ```

Comment: in my case, it's 'rm Podfile'

Answer (score 6):

Use `pod install` command in your ios directory to install new pods in your project. Even if you already have a Podfile and ran pod install before. This should work for you. I ran into the same problem some time ago and this is how it was solved.

Comment: Thanks! I get this error when I do it... [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).

Comment: Does this help ? https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html Please check.. I am not sure why are you getting such error. let me know in comments if things start working.

Comment: Thank you! Updated the pods, this is the only message I keep getting: Warning: Podfile is out of date
  This can cause a mismatched version of Flutter to be embedded in your app, which may result in App Store submission rejection or crashes.
  If you have local Podfile edits you would like to keep, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24641 for instructions.
To regenerate the Podfile, run:
  rm ios/Podfile

Comment: Was everything working before you upgraded your simmulator ?? And I guess simmulator has nothing to do with build.. the issue must be something else..

Comment: Yes, but when I run flutter upgrade, there was an error when updating. So I reinstalled flutter completely...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this will work for everyone, but my issue was fixed by running `flutter run` from the terminal.

I was just using the Flutter launcher from Visual Studio Code and it kept throwing errors.

I had a Podfile already setup, but I think `flutter run` maybe updated it or reinstantiated it? I'm unsure.

My issue was caused by an update to Flutter.

Comment: Keep in mind tho, that this won't report to the debug console

Answer (score 1):

#### Suggestion

After running `flutter clean`

```
pod install --verbose
```

run `pod install --verbose`, because if you use `cloud_firestore` pod install might download [gRPC-Core](https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git) which is approximately 200 MB, but because of it's Git submodules, it will end up downloading 1 GB. So to see progress of what is going on, run

Comment: Re *"So to see progress of what is going on, run"*: Running away doesn't seem like a viable strategy.

Comment: Isn't something missing?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, if someone runs into a problem similar to this output after updating the Podfile:

```
  ld: framework not found intent
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

You can try this:

1. Go to Xcode Select your target.
2. Go to Build Settings.
3. Search the package name shown in the error. e. g. : framework not
   found intent.
4. You will see that there is a section like:
   "Linking"->"Other linker flags" ,then click the bold part of this
   row.
5. It will open a dialog box where you can remove the framework not found.
6. When removing the framework name, also remove the
   "-framework" tag.

This may be related to packages that only work in Android.

Answer (score 1):

If the other solution (`sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`) does not work for you, try the following one instead:

```
gem install --user-install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc
```

After that, run `pod install` or whatever you were trying to do again, but without prefixing it with `arch -x86_64`.

It worked for me without issues and this way I could also avoid going the Intel emulation (Rosetta 2) way.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is:

You try to build with deprecated packages.

First of all, try to update the repository:

```
cd ios && pod repo update
cd ..
```

If this is not fixing the issue, you should do the following steps to clean your repository and update your packages:

```
flutter clean
```

Then update all packages to the major version:

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Then to reload the packages:

```
flutter pub get
```

After that, change the directory into the *ios* folder with (*--verbose* gives you more information):

```
cd ios && pod install --verbose
```

Sometimes here are some error messages about outdated packages. They occur like this:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseAppCheck":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    FirebaseAppCheck (= 9.6.0, ~> 9.6.0-beta)

  In Podfile:
    firebase_app_check (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_app_check/ios`) was resolved to 0.1.2-3, which depends on
      FirebaseAppCheck (~> 10.7.0-beta)


You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * changed the constraints of dependency `FirebaseAppCheck` inside your development pod `firebase_app_check`.
   You should run `pod update FirebaseAppCheck` to apply changes you've made.
```

Then you need to follow the instructions in the error description!

Then change back to the main directory:

```
cd ..
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade your Flutter version. I got similar errors and I tried almost every answer but none of them worked. Then I just upgrade my Flutter version to the latest one and the problem solved.

```
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the *ios* folder and try `pod install --repo-update`.