# Can't subscribe to topic in a Flutter app on iOS using firebase_messaging

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) to manage notifications on a Flutter app.
No problems with Android.
When I try in iOS to subscibe to a topic (again, which WORKS PERFECTLY on Android) I get no error, but I've understood that something bad is happening in the background, since the next line of code is always skipped, exactly like when Flutter goes in exception:

```
void _subscribeToTopic(String topic) async {
    await FCMHelper.firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(topic);
    await SharedPrefsHelper.sp.setBool(topic, true);
}
```

The `await SharedPrefsHelper.sp.setBool(topic, true);` is NEVER executed, meaning that subscribeToTopic is going in error.
I'm astonished that as it seems, nobody had this problem before me (no issue on GitHub, no question on StackOverflow) but I really don't know what to do, especially because I don't know Swift nor Objective-C, so if there is a bug in the code, I'm not able to find it.
Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

solved by deleting and re installing pod files

As what in the following GitHub issue
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1943

To delete and re installing pod files see this link [Flutter iOS build failed an error of pod files: Podfile is out of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59362862/flutter-ios-build-failed-an-error-of-pod-files-podfile-is-out-of-date)