# issue with all >1.2 flutter version on mac

Tags: macos, flutter

17.5 ( last before 1.2 ) and when I try to upgrade to 1.2 or more I have

```
Warning: Podfile is out of date
  This can cause issues if your application depends on plugins that do not support iOS.
  See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#plugin-platforms for details.
  If you have local Podfile edits you would like to keep, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45197 for instructions.
To regenerate the Podfile, run:
  rm ios/Podfile
```

I tried `rm ios/Podfile`

```
rm: ios/Podfile: No such file or directory
```

I follow issue and solution but not working with me ... Or did wrong things

If someone can help me thank you

[Edit] : I remove podfil, and It's ok, thank you for help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59362862/flutter-ios-build-failed-pod-files-error can you try this@Nitneuq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find where your project file is stored in finder. Or by typing find `~/ -type f -name "YOUR PROJECT NAME"` in terminal. list your files by typing `ls` and go into the `ios` file in your flutter project, then type `rm Podfile`. This should delete the podfile, and once you run the project again, the pods will be installed via flutter

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do here is regenerate the iOS Project.
If you have made any changes to the native solution (Xcode), meaning new view controllers, assets, or video files, etc, then make sure to back those up first.

Then delete the iOS project, from your flutter project workspace, and run the following command:

```
flutter create  -i swift .
```

This will generate a swift solution, but if you're looking for objective-c then try this:

```
flutter create  -i objc .
```

After the iOS project is recreated, you will need to clean the project, then make sure that the podfile exists in your project directory.

Then run:

```
cd ios
podfile install
```

After the podfile installs all the required dependencies, try a fresh deployment of your iOS project:

```
flutter run -d "Device Name" --release
```

But make sure that you are running flutter on the root directory, so:

```
cd ..
```