# Flutter not running in Android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-layout

The output of `flutter doctor`

[image]

When running from the Run button in [image]

But getting this error:
[image]

But running this from terminal its running but from run button its causing this problem.

Comment: try This command `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593939/cocoapods-not-installed-or-not-in-valid-state

Comment: @AnmolMishra Still same error.

Comment: @Priyaank Still same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59362862/flutter-ios-build-failed-an-error-of-pod-files-podfile-is-out-of-date/63506237

Comment: @AnmolMishra Still same error