Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected `end'
[!] Invalid Podfile file: syntax error, unexpected `end'.
 #  


odfile:25
#  -------------------------------------------
#    end
>  end
#
#  -------------------------------------------
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:335:in `rescue in block in from_ruby'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:329:in `block in from_ruby'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in `instance_eval'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in `initialize'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:327:in `new'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:327:in `from_ruby'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:293:in `from_file'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:206:in `podfile'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 16 Pro Max.
Hello,
Has anyone had this error from a Flutter mobile project?

can you share your podfile details. Please give more information, it should be with your podfile formatting.

Please improve code section with no zombie or blank sections

This might answer your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59405918/8764293
Basically we are removing the auto generated podfile.
then do
cd ios && pod install

